# htaccess to redirect to multiple slim apps

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am hosting multiple php slim apps on the same web server. The APIs are stored on my server with the following pattern:

```
www.example.com/apis/{appID}/{appVersion}/api.php
```

For example:

```
www.example.com/apis/app1/version2/api.php

www.example.com/apis/app1/version38/api.php

www.example.com/apis/app99/version7/api.php
```

Currently, I have to manually enter a new .htaccess entry everytime I create a new app or create a new app version like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule apis/app18/version1/(.*)$ apis/app18/version1/api.php [L]
```

I was wondering if there is a way to have one .htaccess entry that will redirect files matching the pattern above so that I don't have create a manual entry for every single app and version combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api.php$
RewriteRule ^apis/(\w+/\w+)/.*$ /apis/$1/api.php [L]
```